# How to use/add existing Media Library widget into a custom widget in Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm writing a custom widget, I want to create a form that contains an image picker that selects the image from the existing media library. I've noticed that I could use the existing Media Library widget, but I have no idea how to include it in my widget. Can I import it from the EditPart view somehow ?

[Update]
Here is part of a sample code. Assuming you have this Edit Part template:

```
@using MediaLibrary.FilePicker //Is there a way to add it doing something like this??
@model Maps.Models.MapPart

<fieldset>
  <legend>Map Fields</legend>

   <div class="editor-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Latitude)
   </div>
   <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Latitude)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Latitude)
   </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Longitude)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Longitude)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Longitude)
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

I was trying to use the image picker from my custom widget. Here are the steps that I followed to accomplish this.

1.Add a reference to the MediaPicker libary into my Widget project. 
2.Add the following code:

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions
@using Orchard.MediaPicker
@model MyWidget.Models.PickerForm
<div class="editor-label">
    <label for="ImageUrl">Image Url</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImagePath, new { @class = "text single-line", @id = "ImageUrl" })<br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ImagePath)<br />
    <input type="button" class="button" id="PickImageUrl" value="Pick Image" />
</div>
@using (Script.Foot())
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var baseUrl = "@HttpContext.Current.Request.ToRootUrlString().TrimEnd('/')";
        $("#PickImageUrl").click(function () {
            $("form").trigger("orchard-admin-pickimage-open",
            {
                img: $("#ImageUrl").val(),
                uploadMediaPath: "About",
                callback: function (data) {
                    $("#ImageUrl").val(baseUrl + data.img.src);
                }
            });
        });
    });
//]]>
</script>
}
```

And voila.

Comment: You're hard-coding the id of the field here, instead of using the standard practice of using prefixes. That will cause conflicts. Instead, use `Html.IdFor(m => m.ImagePath)` to get the runtime id of the textbox. You can then use that in the script instead of the hard-coded `#ImageUrl`.

Comment: Thank you @BertrandLeroy that's a good observation. I'll do that change.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a media library picker field.

Comment: Could you be more specific on how to add this media library to my Edit views? or if needed, to my ContentPart class? sorry, I'm kind of lost here. So far I've just created new widgets but haven't used existing ones inside my new widgets.

Comment: You can't use a widget inside another widget, but you can add a field to a widget content type. Just go to content definitions and add a media library picker field to your widget's content type, or add the field from your migration. Either way is much, much simpler than reproducing the script for the image picking.